# Power BI count rows with same ID

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables, one with unique ID's ('Risk Finder') and one with many ID's ('All Accidents full'). In 'All Accidents full' there is a column with binary 1s and 0s to denote if something happen within a time range specified ('All Accidents full'[Three Year BAU]). In 'Risk Finder' I'm trying to create a column that counts the number of rows with a 1 in that binary column for each unique ID.

I've tried a combination of Calculate(Countax), Calculate(Sum) and Countrows, but nothing seems to work.

`CALCULATE(COUNTAX('All Accidents full','All Accidents full'[Three Year BAU]),'Risk Finder'[ID])`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think you just need COUNT and a filter.

```
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( 'All Accidents full'[ID] ),
    'All Accidents full'[Three Year BAU] = 1
)
```

Comment: This is returning the sum of the 'All Accidents full'[Three Year BAU] for each row in 'Risk Finder'

Comment: Do you not have a relationship set up between the tables?

Comment: they're both linked to a ID Key, maybe I need to check the cross filter direction